# In CIDER is it possible to use M-. to jump to definition without the REPL running?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

This CIDER feature only seems to work after executing cider-jack-in:

> M-.   Jump to the definition of a symbol. If invoked with a prefix
>   argument, or no symbol is found at point, prompt for a symbol.

When I open a new clj file and it just says cider[not connected] the `M-.` key combo gives me `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

Is it possible to use this feature without starting and connecting to a REPL? Is there another way to get the same behavior without using CIDER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIDER doesn't have such ability, because it performs look-ups of symbol definitions using metadata attached to vars:

```
> (defn x [] 0)
#'user/x
> (meta #'x)
{... :line <line_nuber>, :file <file_path> ...}
```

Obviously, to have metadata attached you need to start the REPL and evaluate symbol definitions.

Without REPL you may try using `rgrep` (after placing cursor on needed symbol):

```
M-x rgrep <RET>
```

However, this is only a textual search. It will give you all occurrences of symbol in the specified directory (no namespace resolution as well).